# function callback not working with cloudant.db

Tags: nosql, cloudant

I am trying to insert a document in a cloudant NoSQL db but when I execute this function, it goes until "console.log(db)" but doesnt execute the createDocument function. I can´t figure out why. Thank you!

```
function addCard(id, title, texto){
    
    var cloudant = new Cloudant({ url: '...', plugins: { iamauth: { iamApiKey: '...' } } });
    
    cloudant.db.list(function(err, body) {
body.forEach(function(db) {
 console.log(db);
 var createDocument = function(callback) {
  console.log("Creating document 'mydoc'");
  // specify the id of the document so you can update and delete it later
  db.insert({ _id: 'mydoc', a: 1, b: 'two' }, function(err, data) {
    console.log('Error:', err);
    console.log('Data:', data);
    callback(err, data);
  });
};
 
 });
});
    

    
    console.log(id, title, texto);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I´d like to add how I solved it. It was unnecesary to create the function in my case. A friend helped me and here is how it is now (and working).

```
  const cloudant = new Cloudant({
    url: "...",
    plugins: { iamauth: { iamApiKey: "..." } },
  });
  cloudant.use("dbName").insert({ *doc content* });
  console.log("Datos subidos con éxito");
```